# Jurassic World the Game age problem

Tags: facebook, jurassic-world-the-game

I got JWTG when I was 10 on my mother's phone, and a few years ago she gave me that phone so I still had JWTG. I'm over 13 now, is there a way I can change the age on my account so I can sign in to Facebook? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You must contact Tech Support to change the type of account (to Over 13).

Similar solution was found here:

https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/152187-jurassic-world-the-game/74402990

Comment: Thanks and I did but a robot ANSWERED me saying thanks for being patient and understanding because ludia apparently getting a lot of contacts

Comment: You can contact them using the form on the website so you will not have to wait on the phone for an operator :  https://ludia.helpshift.com/a/jurassic-world-alive/

Comment: Oh lol I contacted them in game

Comment: I couldn't find a form

Comment: NVM I switched to desktop view and it pulled up